# Android how to create a 7 inch tablet virtual machine that layouts like a tablet? 2.3.3

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, tablet

I'm driving to make a virtual machine for 7 inch tables but whatever I make tends to be a big screen that displays the layout like a phone. When I use the GUI designer with the 7 inch tablet option it lays out right and even displays good on a real 7 inch tablet, but on the emulator it shows up like a phone and does not layout correctly.

I see several questions on this but none have gotten rid of the phone layout issue.

How would I get this to work?

Comment: Can you tell me the settings you have done in creating your AVD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method did not work for me.

I looked up documentation on googles site to determine screensizes and that is what I used to create a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

To get the official Samsung Galaxy Tab emulator do the following:

1) Open the Android SDK and AVD Manager

2) Click on Available packages

3) Expand the Third party Add-ons. There you will see Samsung Electronics add-ons.

4) Once the add-on is installed create a new emulator. Under Target you will see the new Samsung Tab settings, select that.

That's it!